# Is there a way to automate turning a BizTalk Receive Location on or off through code?

Tags: c#, biztalk, biztalk2006r2

Is there a way to automate the turning on or off of a Receive Location in BizTalk? It seems like there should be some kind of API or some such for this kind of thing. I would prefer to work in C#, but WMI or some kind of script would work too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Besides ExplorerOM, as you've found out, you can also enable/disable receive locations (and control send ports) using WMI.

I have a sample PowerShell script that shows how to do those things [here](http://github.com/tomasr/bts-ps-scripts/blob/master/bts-ports.ps1), if you're interested.

Comment: Great, this is definitely valid. The more options the better. Thanks tomasr.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. It appears that the Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM.dll is what I wanted. Here is an excerpt from the BizTalk documentation that should get anyone else started:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM;
public static void EnumerateOrchestrationArtifacts()
{
    // Connect to the local BizTalk Management database
    BtsCatalogExplorer catalog = new BtsCatalogExplorer();
    catalog.ConnectionString = "Server=.;Initial Catalog=BizTalkMgmtDb;Integrated Security=SSPI;";

    // Enumerate all orchestrations and their ports/roles
    Console.WriteLine("ORCHESTRATIONS: ");
    foreach(BtsAssembly assembly in catalog.Assemblies)
    {
        foreach(BtsOrchestration orch in assembly.Orchestrations)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(" Name:{0}\r\n Host:{1}\r\n Status:{2}",
                orch.FullName, orch.Host.Name, orch.Status);

            // Enumerate ports and operations
            foreach(OrchestrationPort port in orch.Ports)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0} ({1})", 
                    port.Name, port.PortType.FullName);

                foreach(PortTypeOperation operation in port.PortType.Operations)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t\t" + operation.Name);
                }
            }

            // Enumerate used roles
            foreach(Role role in orch.UsedRoles)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0} ({1})", 
                    role.Name, role.ServiceLinkType);

                foreach(EnlistedParty enlistedparty in role.EnlistedParties)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t\t" + enlistedparty.Party.Name);
                }
            }

            // Enumerate implemented roles
            foreach(Role role in orch.ImplementedRoles)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0} ({1})", 
                    role.Name, role.ServiceLinkType);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One caveat, apparently this dll does not support 64 bit. Since I am only writing a simple utility it's not a big deal for me (just compiling as 32-bit), but it is something to be aware of.

Comment: can I use for access remotely to Biztalk Server ??

Comment: Hey Alhambraeidos, if I understand you correctly yes you can. I used this to create a small windows app that let me select a receive location and turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

Glad to see that you seem to have found a solution.

Wanted to mention a similar alternative which is also using Powershell, ExplorerOM, and the BizTalk API to set BizTalk artifacts to various statuses.

Receive Locations being one of them.

The script accepts XML configuration files, where you list the artifacts and what status you would like to set them to.

The script has been published to Microsoft Script Center:
http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Set-Artifact-Status-270f43a0

Answer (score 0):

In response to Alhambraeidos comment. Here's is some excerpts of code I used in a Windows app to disable a Receive Location remotely:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the biz talk catalog.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The biz talk catalog.</value>
    private BtsCatalogExplorer BizTalkCatalog { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the biz talk artifacts.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeBizTalkCatalogExplorer()
    {
        // Connect to the local BizTalk Management database
        BizTalkCatalog = new BtsCatalogExplorer();
        BizTalkCatalog.ConnectionString = "server=BiztalkDbServer;database=BizTalkMgmtDb;integrated security=true";
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the location from biz talk.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="locationName">Name of the location.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private ReceiveLocation GetLocationFromBizTalk(string locationName)
    {
        ReceivePortCollection receivePorts = BizTalkCatalog.ReceivePorts;
        foreach (ReceivePort port in receivePorts)
        {
            foreach (ReceiveLocation location in port.ReceiveLocations)
            {
                if (location.Name == locationName)
                {
                    return location;
                }
            }
        }

        throw new ApplicationException("The following receive location could not be found in the BizTalk Database: " + locationName);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Turns the off receive location.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="vendorName">Name of the vendor.</param>
    public void TurnOffReceiveLocation(string vendorName)
    {
        ReceiveLocation location = Locations[vendorName].ReceiveLocation;
        location.Enable = false;
        BizTalkCatalog.SaveChanges();
    }
```

You'll notice that there is some I left out, like I was creating a dictionary of receive locations called "Locations", but you should be able to get the idea. The pattern pretty much holds true for any BizTalk object you want to interact with.